# Jquery Mobile Table Reflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create my own script for a mobile version of my tables on my website.

Im currently using the script below to get the size of the table, and create new tables for each row, duplicating the headers into each new table....   (see: http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/ ) to get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

My script is as follows, but their is a js fiddle included at the bottom for a better example.

My problem is that I am only able to create 1 inside each table, where it should really be 3 rows, inside of each table. Again check the fiddle below for a proper example. Can anyone see why it is only creating 1 row in the table?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var TableSize = $("table thead tr th").not("table.mobile_table thead tr th").size(); // Get # of columns
var i = 1;
var TableRowCount = $("table tbody tr").size(); // Get # of body rows
$("table thead tr th").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", i++); // Give headers incrementing ID
});
for ( var CreateTables = 1;  CreateTables < TableRowCount; CreateTables++ ){ // Create new table           class="mobile_table" for each row 
$("table").after("<table class='mobile_table'></table>");
}   
$("table.mobile_table").each(function(){// Insert original headers into each row of new table as first column
 var h = 1;
 while ( ++h < TableSize){ // this is where the error is, it gives me the stuff below but x3 (the number of created tables)......

    $("table.mobile_table").after("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"); 

 }
});
console.log(TableSize);
console.log(TableRowCount);
});
  </script>
```

See the fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/Yf7KV/

Comment: It's creating 3 rows but one column. Do you mean you need 3 columns too ?

Comment: It's creating 3 tables (a table for each row of the original table)

Comment: Each of these tables should contain a row for each th of the original table.

Comment: Each table has red border

Comment: Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yf7KV/1/

Comment: That is the output I'm looking for, but hardcoding it in the js accomplishes nothing. There will be multiple table with of different sizes, that is why I count the number of headers of the original table, so i can dynamically create the correct number of rows. But thank you! Thought you had it there for a second.

Comment: var h = 1;
  while ( h++ < TableSize){// Create rows based on number of headers

This i thought should create the correct number of rows....

Comment: Okay, here you go: Use `append` http://jsfiddle.net/Yf7KV/2/

Comment: Also, `TableSize = 6` hence you get 6 rows not three

Comment: My bad, you are correct.

Comment: Also, start the count of `h` from 0 to get the exact number of `tablesize` or `tablerowcount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Yf7KV/2/

**JS**

```
$(this).append("<tr><td class='mobile_col_1'>Col 1</td><td class='mobile_col_2'>Col 2</td></tr>");
```

**Explanation**: `Append` will alllow you to append elements one after the another. `html` replaces with what you currently have